# Is there a way to tell if one tweet was created after another based on the tweet id?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Currently I'm checking if a tweet was created after another tweet based on the timestamp, but this is proving inconsistent. What is working locally is not working all the time on my server. I suspect a timezone issue (my server is in another time zone).

But I was wondering if I can do this based on Twitter's unique ids for each tweet? Something in the form:

```
if (tweet2.id > tweet1.id) {
    // tweet2 created after tweet 1
} else {
    // tweet2 created before tweet 1
}
```

Is this possible? If not I'll ask another question about what could be going wrong with my date implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Twitter ids are generated by [twitter snowflake](https://blog.twitter.com/2010/announcing-snowflake) mechanism which
  is an algorithm and a cluster of machines to produce it. In general
  those id's are sequential so your comparison will basically hold. The
  problem is those id's are currently > 64 bits so js will truncate
  those. The trick is to use tweetXXX.id_str field which is the id
  casted to a string for your comparison.
- I haven't see your date implementation but probably you are no comparing UTC date values. Any way comparison made on datetime will not give you correct results even on ms scale there will be many tweets on same date time.

Comment: Thanks although I'm a bit confused as to the footnote on that link: In mathematical terms, although the tweets will no longer be sorted, they will be k-sorted. We’re aiming to keep our k below 1 second, meaning that tweets posted within a second of one another will be within a second of one another in the id space too. I'll be comparing the tweets of a single user at a time so they shouldn't be posting quicker than a second. Will the sort logic still hold?

Comment: Well, I just updated my code and it is working better than my old implementation. I think for my purposes I can be confident that comparing tweet Ids and assuming they are sequential is valid. I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: if you compare tweets posted just by you the datetime comparison will hold, I though you were comparing tweets coming from tweet stream or something.

Comment: I thought the date time comparison would work, but for whatever reason it didn't. This seems less error prone for me to use so I'll go with that.